# Compile C source files from tree into build directory with make

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have a Makefile that looks similar to this condensed version:

```
.PHONY: all

CC  = gcc -O3 -fPIC
SRC = $(shell find src -type f -name '*.c')
OBJ = $(addprefix build/, $(notdir $(SRC:.c=.o))
TGT = build/prog

all: $(TGT)

$(TGT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $+ -o $@

build/%.o: src/a/%.c
    $(CC) -c $+ -o $@

build/%.o: src/b/%.c
    $(CC) -c $+ -o $@

build/%.o: src/c/d/%.c
    $(CC) -c $+ -o $@
```

I would like to combine the `build/%.o` rules into one rule because the real makefile has like twenty of these for various paths in the `src` directory. But whatever I tried nothing works. I'm sure there must be a solution, please enlighten me how this can be done.

Comment: Assuming you're using GNU make you mightwant to look at the [`vpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search) directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment you can make use of GNU make's [`vpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search) directive...

```
.PHONY: all

CC  = gcc -O3 -fPIC
SRC = $(shell find src -type f -name '*.c')
OBJ = $(addprefix build/, $(notdir $(SRC:.c=.o))
TGT = build/prog

all: $(TGT)

$(TGT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $+ -o $@

# Use vpath to give make a colon (or space) separated list
# of directories in which to look for .c files.
#
vpath %.c src/a:src/b:src/c/d

build/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $+ -o $@
```

Since you're using `find` to locate the source files you could go a step further and use the results of that `find` to generate the `vpath`...

```
.PHONY: all

CC  = gcc -O3 -fPIC
SRC = $(shell find src -type f -name '*.c')
OBJ = $(addprefix build/, $(notdir $(SRC:.c=.o))
TGT = build/prog

all: $(TGT)

$(TGT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $+ -o $@

# Use vpath to give make a colon (or space) separated list
# of directories in which to look for .c files.  Make use of
# the $(SRC) variable to generate the list of paths automatically.
#
SRC_DIRS := $(sort $(dir $(SRC)))
vpath %.c $(SRC_DIRS)

build/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $+ -o $@
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if there are other answers (I dislike the vpath option for some reason).

Comment: Can I ask why you dislike `vpath`?  Just curious.

Comment: I have several parts in my make file where i have to change the vpath between. If there is a solution where I don't have to then i could freely rearrange the rules inside the make file. But mainly it's just a feeling ... :)

Comment: What you're asking for (and the solution described here), both have a sharp stick -- if you ever have two files in different directories, but with the same name, then only one of them will get compiled.   This is fine as long as you have a small, stable project.   It doesn't scale well to really large projects.